# Is it possible to send python requests data in format "&username=login&password=password"

Tags: python, python-requests

I need to send python requests data in application/x-www-form-urlencoded. Couldn;t find the answer. It must be that format otherwise the web won;t pass me :(

Comment: https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/quickstart/#passing-parameters-in-urls

Comment: You can also just put that data into the URL manually, you know.

Comment: Whilst you can.. you definitely shouldn't, any request logs would include that raw password and username and would be a massive security hole

Answer (score 0, accepted):

simple request should work

```
import requests    
url = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded&username=login&password=password'    
r = requests.get(url)
```

or a JSON post:

```
import requests
r = requests.post('application/x-www-form-urlencoded', json={"username": "login","password": password})
```

Comment: lets say my page is called testpage so the post will be testpage/x-www-form-urlencoded&username=login&password=password' ??

Comment: Probably. Maybe:  testpage/x-www-form-urlencoded/username=login&password=password